# How can I close the MainForm, without closing the others?

Tags: c#, forms

So, I'm writing a Hangman, and at the MainForm you have to choose if you want to play single player or multiplayer. When I choose which one I want, this MainForm should close( I use this.Close() ) and trigger another Form, but instead the entire program shuts down.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Form f2 = new Form1();
     f2.Show();
     this.Close();           
}
```

If in Programs.cs I modify the code like this:

```
Form f4 = new Form4();
f4.Show();          
Application.Run();
```

everything goes well, but If I won't exit the program using Application.Exit(), it will still run in the background.

So, how could I solve this problem?

Comment: What about this.Hide() ?

Comment: You need to call `Application.Exit()` on the other form's `FormClosed` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a basic form that will pretty much just allow the user to play until they close the other form then close this form, use this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form f2 = new Form1();
    this.Hide();
    f2.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();           
}
```

or something a bit more fancy will allow you to close the form if the user selects something like not wanting to play another game or change difficulty settings or whatever.  You can do that like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form f2 = new Form1();
    this.Hide();
    if(f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can't close the parent form and keep the children alive.**

Use `this.Hide()` instead of `this.Close()`

Then on the `Form2_FormClosed` Event you can do `Application.Exit()`
or you can even show the MainForm Again.

**OR:**

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
this.Visible = false;
f2.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

Comment: Hide basically closes it from the user's point of view.  You can show dialog on the subform, so when it closes you can determine whether you shut down the program or show the main form again.

Answer (score 0):

You can show (dialog) your form before Application.Run(new MainForm()), so you don't need to close the Mainform